# : java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver when tryingt to run a Python Script on Databricks cluster using Databricks Connect

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to run a Python Script from Visual Studio code on Databricks Cluster using Databricks connect. The jar files for the [Apache Spark connector: SQL Server & Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver15) have been installed on the Databricks Cluster.

However I am getting the error:

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o42.save.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, DataFrame
from db_connection import fetch_db_config
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark import sql
from IPython.display import display



##Fetch Data from delta table into Data frame
def fetch_data_from_delta(
  spark: SparkSession, 
  sql: sql
  ): 
  global df
  df = spark.sql("select * from lending_club_acc_loans limit 10000")
  # newdf = df.repartition(8)
  return df

def load_df_to_db():
  
  jdbchostname, jdbcurl, jdbcusername, jdbcpassword, connection_properties = fetch_db_config()

  try:
    df.write \
      .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
      .mode("overwrite") \
      .option("url", jdbcurl) \
      .option("dbtable", "lending_club_acc_loans") \
      .option("user", jdbcusername) \
      .option("password", jdbcpassword) \
      .option("tableLock", "true") \
      .option("batchsize", "500") \
      .option("reliabilityLevel", "BEST_EFFORT") \
      .save()

  except ValueError as error :
      print("Connector write failed", error)


def run():
  spark = SparkSession.builder.config('spark.driver.extraClassPath','dbfs:/FileStore/jars/18df20ee_ae05_45d0_ba41_89502b080b51-spark_mssql_connector_2_12_3_0_1_0_0_alpha-a6e1c.jar').getOrCreate()

  fetch_data_from_delta(spark, sql)

  load_df_to_db()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Can someone help me figure out the issue?

Comment: what Databricks runtime version & what exact version of Spark connector for MS SQL?

Comment: 7.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.0.1, Scala 2.12)

Comment: Did you add any jar file for sql server? If not, that explains the error

Comment: and what version of connector?

Comment: I have already added the jar file on the cluster. And the version of the connector is Spark 3.0.0 compatible connnector : com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12_3.0:1.0.0-alpha

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. the issue was basically with the jdbcurl parameter passed in the .option code. I hardcoded the url and tested the code and it ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It is JDBC connection. This error occur when connection string is not proper I face same issue in  databrics.

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o42.save. : java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Solution: First you test the connection with simple select query. Once you found database connection is correct then implement original logic.

Hope this will help you.